# Read string array from gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have function that reads string from xml file, for example:

```
<string name="language">en</string>
```

In gradle:

```
readConfiguration('language')

//////

def readConfiguration(data) {
   def stringsFile = android.sourceSets.main.res.sourceFiles.find {    
      it.name.equals 'configuration.xml' 
   }
   return new XmlParser().parse(stringsFile).string.find { 
      it.@name.equals data }.text()
   }
}
```

But how can I read string array like:

```
<string-array name="languages">
    <item>en</item>
     <item>es</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
return new XmlParser().parse(stringsFile).'string-array'.find { it.@name.equals data }.text()
```

It works correctly:

```
def input = '''
<root>
    <string-array name="languages">
        <item>en</item>    
        <item>es</item>
    </string-array>
</root>
'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(input)
assert xml.'string-array'.find { it.@name.equals('languages') }.text() == 'enes'
```